# Benefits of using mediumint instead of int for primary key columns?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-performance

I inherited a database where the previous developer used a mix of `mediumint` and `int` for key columns.  I am now going through the database and trying to add foreign keys and I have run into some problems because of type mismatches between key columns on separate tables.

Example:

```
Company
--------
Id (int)
Name (whatever)

Employee
---------
Id (mediumint)
CompanyId(mediumint)
Name (whatever)
```

[From what I understand](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html), using `mediumint` will save me one byte of storage (but also limits me to a bit over 8 million rows).

I would prefer to just move everything over to `int`, but I'm wondering if there are there going to be any noticeable benefits from using `mediumint` over `int`?

Comment: The only other thing I could see is they have different ranges of acceptable values. Beside that, it's all about the storage. Also I don't understand why employee would be mediumInt while company is a int. There are way more employees than companies.

Comment: Apart from the ranges, the only difference is the storage size: it can save space when you have *millions* of rows, which could in turn help MySQL to find the data more quickly, but I wouldn't worry about it if this less than a few million rows.

Comment: If you only see benefits at a few million rows and you run out of space at 8 million it seems like it might not be worth it unless you are certain that you will never crack 8 million.

Comment: @Marc, that is just a made up example but the real database is almost as screwy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, scanning a MEDIUMINT key is faster than scanning an INT key. The difference is usually not so big. However, your problem sounds strange to me: if your PK can be MEDIUMINT, than any FK referring to it should be MEDIUMINT. How is it possible that FKs contain bigger values?

Comment: It's not possible.  There are currently no foreign keys defined, I am trying to add them, but before I do that I want the datatypes to sync up.

Comment: Of course. But suppose you are going to make this FK: tab1.a -> tab2.a. If MAX(tab1.a) > 65535, then MAX(tab2.a) should be > 65535, too. So, what is the problem in changing both columns to MEDIUMINT?

Comment: There is no problem in that exact scenario.  The problems come if you are using mediumint for a table that could have more than 8 million rows some day.  I think there is a much greater chance of me running out of ids compared to the chance of me experiencing performance problems as a result of me using `int` instead of `mediumint`.

Comment: In that case, don't change the type. Stackoverflow users don't know your databases :)

Comment: Well I have to change the types since the two columns are different types at the moment.  I'm just electing to go with int instead of mediumint :)